# in R, how to distribution data into different group

Tags: r

i have group like 1-10 , 10-20, 20-30, 30-40. and i have data like "1,23,24,11,33,22,5,6,7,8,3,2"
how can i find out how many in each group

Comment: You can do what you need using the which function (e.g. length(which(data >= 1 & data < 10))). If you describe in more detail how exactly are your groups represented, you might get a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also use the hist function:

```
y <- c(1,23,24,11,33,22,5,6,7,8,3,2)
h <- hist(y, seq(0, 40, 10), plot=0) # plot=0 avoids plotting the histogram
# Refer to h$counts to get the counts in each bin
```

Answer (score 2):

```
R> table(cut(c(1,23,24,11,33,22,5,6,7,8,3,2), 
             breaks=seq(0, 40, by=10), right=FALSE))

 [0,10) [10,20) [20,30) [30,40) 
      7       1       3       1
```