# Add column into a dataframe based on condition

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like this but with 20 levels.

```
df <- data.frame(
    x = factor(c("alpha","beta","gamma","delta")),
    y = factor(c("alpha","beta","gamma","delta")),
    z = factor(c("alpha","beta","gamma","delta"))
```

I would like to create a column within a dataframe based on three other columns.

```
df$w<-with(df,ifelse(df$z==df$x,df$y,df$x))
```

But it does not give back the content of the columns, just levels.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R adding column which contains bin value of another column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570293/r-adding-column-which-contains-bin-value-of-another-column)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT:
Your code is NOT Wrong.
You just have to reconvert your result into factor like this:

```
 df<-data.frame(B=c("A","B","C","C"), C=c("A","C","B","B"), D=c("B","A","C","A") )   
df$A<-levels(df$B)[with(df,ifelse(df$B==df$C,df$D,df$C))]
```

To see why this happen you have to see what ifelse does:

```
debugonce(ifelse)
ifelse(df$B==df$C,df$D,df$C)
```

Keep in Mind  "Factor variables are stored, internally, as numeric variables together with their levels. The actual values of the numeric variable are 1, 2, and so on."
In particular ifelse assign to the answer  vector boolean values, that is you start with a logical vector. Then based on test comparison, ifelse subset this ans vector assigning "yes" values. So R keep the  vector rapresentation.

Briefly something like this happen and you lose the factor rapresentation

```
   a<-c(TRUE,FALSE)
   a[1]<-df$D[1]
   df$D
   a
```

Try also this working example (an alternative way to do the same thing)

```
df<-data.frame(B=c("A","B","C","C"), C=c("A","C","B","B"), D=c("B","A","C","A") )

f<-data.frame(b,c,d)
df
f<-function(x,y,z){
  if(x==y){
    z
  }else{
    y
  }
}

df$A<-unlist(Map(f,df$B,df$C,df$D))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I understand the underlying logic, but I don't see in your example where I have my `df$A` variable back? Tried to apply but not sure what to do.

Comment: Hi, I tried to edit and  to make it clearer. If you have further doubts feel free to ask

Comment: It now works. Thanks a lot for the time you've put in this.

Answer (score -1):

Works for me?

```
 df <- data.frame(B=c("A","B","C","C"), C=c("A","C","B","B"), D=c("B","A","C","A") )

 df$A<-ifelse(df$B==df$C,paste(df$D),paste(df$C))

 return(df)
```

Comment: Because your example data isn't a set of factors, like OP has. Try - `df <- data.frame(B=c("A","B","C","C"), C=c("A","C","B","B"), D=c("B","A","C","A") )`

Comment: No, I mean your input `df` isn't a set of `factor`s, which is necessary to reproduce this problem.