# mutate case _when error in R

Tags: r, case-when, dplyr

Can someone tell me what is wrong with this chunk of code:

```
df %>% mutate(age2=case_when(
    age %in% 0:20 ~ "A"
    age %in% 20:40 ~ "B"
    age %in% 40:60 ~ "C"
    age %in% 60:80 ~ "D"
    age %in% 80:100 ~ "E"
     T ~ ""))
```

I get error saying: Error: unexpected symbol in:
"age %in% 0:20 ~ "A" I believe ~ is the problem, but not sure how to solve it.

Thank you

Comment: Not sure what happened since you did not provide a reproducible example, but if you are working on numeric data, would you like to try `age > 0 & age <= 20`? It seems to me that the way you assign values could be problematic, not clear if `20` should be in "A" or "B", for example.

Comment: See also `cut` (e.g., [this R-FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5570293/903061)). `age2 = cut(age, breaks = c(-Inf, seq(20.5, 100.5, by = 20)), labels = LETTERS[1:5])`

Comment: oh my god thank you so much for cut!I did not know about this at all

Comment: Thank you @www..your comment started the discussion and I got more than what i wanted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need commas between the cases ([source](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.3/topics/case_when)):

```
df %>% mutate(age2=case_when(
    age %in% 0:20 ~ "A",
    age %in% 20:40 ~ "B",
    age %in% 40:60 ~ "C",
    age %in% 60:80 ~ "D",
    age %in% 80:100 ~ "E",
     T ~ ""))
```

However, you also might want to think about [www](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7669809/www)'s comment in the case that `age` might take a non-integer value.

Comment: @Bioinformatician -- happens to everyone; I'm pretty good at catching it in others' code, but of course not my own...