# Why is my nested ifelse working outside a function but not inside (in R)?

Tags: r, function, if-statement

I am playing with a data frame where one of the columns display the Body Mass Index (BMI) of people, and I want to create a function that takes those BMIs and returns a column with the interpretation of those BMIs (Underweight / normal / etc).

My function takes three arguments: dataframe_name, age and BMI. (The age because interpretation varies for children).

So I try to use a nested `ifelse()` inside my function and the function returns a column that displays only the TRUE argument of the condition in my first `ifelse()`; the others appear like `NA`. But when I do the same code directly to my data frame, it works! Please help! I dont know what I am not seeing...

This is my function (imc stands for BMI in french), and its application to my table

```
        my_function = function(tableau, age, imc){

        stopifnot(age %in% colnames(tableau), imc %in% colnames(tableau))
        stopifnot(is.numeric(tableau[, age]), is.numeric(tableau[, imc]))

        interp = ifelse(tableau$age <= 18, "pas applicable pour enfant", 
                 ifelse(tableau$imc < 16.5, "dénutrition", 
                 ifelse(tableau$imc >= 16.5 & tableau$imc < 18.5, "maigreur",
                 ifelse(tableau$imc >= 18.5 & tableau$imc < 25, "corpulance normale",
                 ifelse(tableau$imc >= 25 & tableau$imc < 30, "surpoids",
                 ifelse(tableau$imc >= 30 & tableau$imc < 35, "obésité modérée",
                 ifelse(tableau$imc >= 35 & tableau$imc < 40, "obésité sévère",
                 ifelse(tableau$imc >= 40, "obésité morbide", "PA")))))))) 
        tableau = cbind(tableau, interpIMC_A = c(interp))
        }
        tab_preuve = my_function(tab_preuve, "age", "IMC")
```

This is how I did it without a function (and it work, while it didn't inside the function)

```
        interp = ifelse(tab_preuve$age <= 18, "pas applicable pour enfant", 
                 ifelse(tab_preuve$IMC < 16.5, "dénutrition", 
                 ifelse(tab_preuve$IMC >= 16.5 & tab_preuve$IMC < 18.5, "maigreur",
                 ifelse(tab_preuve$IMC >= 18.5 & tab_preuve$IMC < 25, "corpulance normale",
                 ifelse(tab_preuve$IMC >= 25 & tab_preuve$IMC < 30, "surpoids",
                 ifelse(tab_preuve$IMC >= 30 & tab_preuve$IMC < 35, "obésité modérée",
                 ifelse(tab_preuve$IMC >= 35 & tab_preuve$IMC < 40, "obésité sévère",
                 ifelse(tab_preuve$IMC >= 40, "obésité morbide", "PA")))))))) 
        tab_preuve = cbind(tab_preuve, IntIMC = c(interp))
```

[This is the table with the result without the function and with the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/daJ6F.png)

Thank you to all who wants to help me (this is driving me crazy!)
PS: Sorry for my english and the long post, I hope it is clear.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Do I understand it correctly, that the "NA" is unexpected?

Comment: You can't use `$` with column names stored in variables. Use `[[` instead. That is, if you have `age <- "AGE"`, `df$age` will look for a column named `"age"`, not `"AGE"`. You need `df[[age]]` and `df[[imc]]` because `age` and `imc` are objects containing column names a strings, not literal column names.

Comment: Also, since your `ifelse` is nested and you arrange your `imc` cutoffs in increasing order, you don't need to bother with the `>=` conditions, the `<` are enough. `...tableau[[imc]] < 16.5, "dénutrition", ifelse(tableau[[imc]] < 18.5, "maigreur", ifelse(tableau[[imc]] < 25, ...`.

Comment: For another way to approach the problem the `cut` function might be easier, [as here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5570360/903061). I think you can simplify to `ifelse(tableau[[age]] <= 18, "pas applicable pour enfant", cut(tableau[[imc]], breaks = c(0, 16.5, 18.5, 25, 30, 35, 40, Inf), labels = c("dénutrition", "maigreur", "corpulance normale", "surpoids", "obésité modérée", "obésité sévère", "obésité morbide")))`

Comment: Gregor - reinstate Monica, Thank you very much for your answers, they solve my problem. I use as.character() to surround cut() for the function to return the labels correctly (otherwise it return integers instead). Thank you to all for your answers, they where really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Could you post a reprex of the data so that it's easier to work out what's the problem?

Generally though, I'd recommend using a `case_when()` function (https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html) from the `dplyr` package. It's a vectorized version of an `if` statement and much easier to work with because it's flat and not nested, so it's easier to spot bugs & syntax errors.

Also, if you're modifying a data frame, you can use it inside a `mutate()` function to make the code even more readable.

E.g.:

````
tableau %>% 
   mutate(imc = case_when(
                  imc < 16.5 ~ "dénutrition",
                  imc >= 1.6 & imc < 18.5 ~ "maigreur",
                  etc...)```
````