# Summarize Dates into Varying Groups

Tags: r

I have a variable that provides miscellaneous dates. I want to summarize these so they can be factored before being used in a predictive model.

I would like to do group the dates by the following:

- This Year (this calendar year)
- Last Year
- Over 3 Years Ago

I'm pretty new to R so any help on this would be much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Please add data using `dput` or something that we can copy and use. Also show expected output for the same.  Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: If your date column is `Date` or `POSIX` class (as it should be), you can use `cut` as you would with integers - [see this FAQ about binning data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5570293/903061).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other commenters have noted, you haven't supplied any data or a reproducible example, but let's give this a go anyway.

I'll be using two tidyverse packages, `dplyr` and `lubridate`, to help us out.

For present purposes, let's start by generating some random dates and put these into a dataframe/tibble. I'm assuming your dates are already within a dataframe in the right class, as Gregor pointed out above.

```
data <- tibble(date = sample(seq(as.Date('2015-01-01'), as.Date('2020-12-31'), by="day"), 50))
```

Let's now use `dplyr` and `lubridate` to recode the dates into a new variable, `date_group`:

```
data %>%
  mutate(date_group = factor(
    case_when(
      year(date) == year(today()) ~ "This Year",
      year(date) == year(today()) - 1 ~ "Last Year",
      year(date) < today() - years(3) ~ "Over 3 Years Ago",
      TRUE ~ "Other"
    )
  ))
```

For the first two groups, we apply use the `lubridate` function `year()` (which extracts the year from a date) to the `date` column in `data`, and compare this against the year extracted from today's date (using `today()`).

For dates over 3 years ago, we subtract 3 years from today's date (noting that this is different from the calendar-year based calculations for this year and last year) using `years()`.

Of course, this leaves a gap for dates less than 3 years ago but more than 1 calendar year ago. We have a default option in the `case_when` function to specify this as "Other".

We wrap the result of the `case_when` function in `factor()` so that the resulting groups are treated as a factor rather than a string ready for subsequent modelling.

The `case_when` function is useful (and easy to read) if you have just a few categories. Too many and it gets too messy and you should think about another way to restructure your data.