# Why aren't double digits numbers included in my "less than" and "greater than" commands?

Tags: r, categorical-data

I am fairly new to R, and I am using it for my thesis. I tried to create a set of commands that recode a range of numeric values as a categorical variable. The range of possible values in my dataset range from 1 - 13. For some reason, all of the values with double digit numbers do not get grouped into the factor level I created, and I don't know why.

Here is my code creating the categorical groups, converting it to factor levels, and the output:

```
> Desc$Number.of.Chronic.conditions[Desc$Number.of.Chronic.conditions <=2] <- "≤2"
> Desc$Number.of.Chronic.conditions[Desc$Number.of.Chronic.conditions >=3 & Desc$Number.of.Chronic.conditions <5] <- "3 - 4"
> Desc$Number.of.Chronic.conditions[Desc$Number.of.Chronic.conditions >=5 & Desc$Number.of.Chronic.conditions <7] <- "5 - 6"
> Desc$Number.of.Chronic.conditions[Desc$Number.of.Chronic.conditions >=7 & Desc$Number.of.Chronic.conditions <9] <- "7 - 8"
> Desc$Number.of.Chronic.conditions[Desc$Number.of.Chronic.conditions >=9] <- "≥9"
> 
> Desc$Number.of.Chronic.conditions <- factor(Desc$Number.of.Chronic.conditions)

> print(Desc$Number.of.Chronic.conditions)
[1] 5 - 6 7 - 8 ≤2    5 - 6 5 - 6 3 - 4 7 - 8 ≤2    7 - 8 3 - 4 5 - 6 ≤2    5 - 6 ≥9    ≤2    5 - 6 5 - 6 7 - 8 10   
[20] 7 - 8 11    7 - 8 5 - 6 ≤2    3 - 4 5 - 6 ≥9    5 - 6 7 - 8 3 - 4 3 - 4 5 - 6 ≤2    ≤2    5 - 6 3 - 4 7 - 8 3 - 4
[39] ≤2    7 - 8 5 - 6 7 - 8 7 - 8 5 - 6 10    ≤2    ≤2    ≤2    ≤2    3 - 4 3 - 4 ≤2    ≤2    ≤2    7 - 8 ≤2    ≤2   
[58] 7 - 8 ≤2    3 - 4 3 - 4 ≤2    13    3 - 4 3 - 4 3 - 4 7 - 8 5 - 6 3 - 4 5 - 6 3 - 4 5 - 6 5 - 6 5 - 6 3 - 4 3 - 4
[77] 5 - 6 ≥9    ≤2    ≤2    10    3 - 4 7 - 8 11    7 - 8 5 - 6 3 - 4 3 - 4 ≥9    3 - 4 3 - 4 5 - 6 3 - 4 7 - 8 5 - 6
[96] 5 - 6 3 - 4 12    10    ≤2    5 - 6 5 - 6 3 - 4 3 - 4 3 - 4 5 - 6 5 - 6 3 - 4 5 - 6 ≤2    5 - 6 3 - 4 5 - 6 3 - 4
[115] 3 - 4 ≤2    5 - 6 7 - 8 3 - 4 ≤2    3 - 4 7 - 8 5 - 6 7 - 8 5 - 6 ≤2    7 - 8 ≤2    ≤2    ≥9    7 - 8 ≥9    3 - 4
[134] 5 - 6 ≤2    5 - 6 3 - 4 ≤2    3 - 4 3 - 4 ≤2    5 - 6 3 - 4 ≤2    7 - 8 3 - 4 ≤2    ≤2    3 - 4 3 - 4 ≤2    10   
[153] 3 - 4 5 - 6 5 - 6 5 - 6 5 - 6 3 - 4 5 - 6 5 - 6 5 - 6 7 - 8 5 - 6 5 - 6 5 - 6 10    5 - 6 3 - 4 3 - 4 ≤2    3 - 4
[172] ≤2    7 - 8 ≤2    ≤2    7 - 8 ≤2    7 - 8 10    5 - 6 ≥9    3 - 4 3 - 4
Levels: ≤2 ≥9 10 11 12 13 3 - 4 5 - 6 7 - 8

> summary(Desc$Number.of.Chronic.conditions)
   ≤2    ≥9    10    11    12    13 3 - 4 5 - 6 7 - 8 
   40     7     7     2     1     1    49    49    27
```

Comment: Share your data in a [reproducible format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) such as with `dput()` so we can copy/paste into R. You seem to be assigning a numeric column non-numeric values which will force it to character values. This is generally a bad idea. You want to do all the reassigning in one step with something like `cut()` or `dplyr::case_when()` instead

Comment: Is the variable Number.of.Chronic.conditions numeric? Otherwise, you should convert it to a numeric first.

Comment: Suggested duplicate: [Add column which contains binned values of a numeric column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5570293/903061)

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I was able to add a column of binned values using cut() and it seemed to have done the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you start with a vector of integers, when you write a character string into a vector of integers the whole vector is converted to strings.

See:

```
Desc<-data.frame(Number.of.Chronic.conditions=c(1:15))

str(Desc)  ## str shows the structure of an object
'data.frame':   15 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ Number.of.Chronic.conditions: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ... 

Desc$Number.of.Chronic.conditions[Desc$Number.of.Chronic.conditions <=2] <- "≤2"

str(Desc)
'data.frame':   15 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ Number.of.Chronic.conditions: chr  "≤2" "≤2" "3" "4" ...
```

The rules for >= of an integer are different from strings. Both "9" and 9 are >= 9; however "10" is not >= 9.

There are at least two ways to solve this, perform all the binning in one step using a function like the `dplyr` library's `mutate(case_when(...)))`, or push the binned factor into its own column:

```
Desc<-data.frame(Number.of.Chronic.conditions=c(1:15))

Desc$Factor.of.Chronic.conditions[Desc$Number.of.Chronic.conditions <=2] <- "≤2"
Desc$Factor.of.Chronic.conditions[Desc$Number.of.Chronic.conditions >=3 & Desc$Number.of.Chronic.conditions <5] <- "3 - 4"
Desc$Factor.of.Chronic.conditions[Desc$Number.of.Chronic.conditions >=5 & Desc$Number.of.Chronic.conditions <7] <- "5 - 6"
Desc$Factor.of.Chronic.conditions[Desc$Number.of.Chronic.conditions >=7 & Desc$Number.of.Chronic.conditions <9] <- "7 - 8"
Desc$Factor.of.Chronic.conditions[Desc$Number.of.Chronic.conditions >=9] <- "≥9"

Desc$Factor.of.Chronic.conditions <- factor(Desc$Factor.of.Chronic.conditions)

table(Desc$Factor.of.Chronic.conditions)
```